# Add generic EntityObject to ObjectContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

how is it possible to add EntityObject instance into ObjectContext? I do not want to use specialized functions for adding specific entities. How can one do that?
I want to have one function for adding any entity to the context.

Thank you in advance.

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<YourEntityType>().AddObject(yourEntity)`. There is no single method which will take any entity type's instance without any other information and add it to the context.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ObjectContext.AddObject(string entitySetName, object entity)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject.aspx)

...although you still have to pass the name of the Entity Set that you're adding the object to.

Comment: Thank you. But this is precisely I do not want to pass. Can one avoid entitySetName?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a naming convention that you use on your sets...

> example:
>
> **Entity Name**: Person
>
> **Entity Set Name**: PersonSet

Then you can put a wrapper in front of Justin's example...

Basically....the signature would look like so...

```
ObjectContext.Add(object entity)
```

Under the covers, it would grab the type name of the entity instance, and use that to build the set name based upon your convention, and then make the call to ObjectContext.AddObject(string entitySetName, object entity)